# Data load from a txt file into oracle database

Tags: oracle

**File.txt:**

```
Itemnumber  20
Quantity    2
Itemname    Rubber
```

Need help to load this data into a table?

I feel a ctl file can load the data into table. I came across loading of CSV, position based load (position 1:10). Can you help me in loading the above file?

```
Select * from stationary
Item_number,quantity,item_name
```

are the column.

Comment: Please show the results of what you have tried.  Results will go to the .log file.  Does this set of 3 rows which really comprise a record repeat? Are you able to preprocess the record to get just the data elements by themselves on one line?

Comment: Could there be NULL values?

Answer (score 1):

This works although I strongly encourage you to get the data provider to give you the data in the proper format for loading, or do some pre-processing to build the proper format yourself first.  I would consider this a last resort as the REGEXP functions are expensive and if this file is huge it will most likely take a long time to process.  Anyway we have all had to deal with crap data from vendors and have had to do what we have to do so whatever :-)

The `CONCATENATE 3` clause tells `sqlldr` to combine every 3 lines into 1 line before processing.  Then the task is to get the data elements out of that line.

`sqlldr` reads the line and since no delimiters are defined the entire line is effectively one field and matches up with the first field in the control file, TEMP.  TEMP does not match a column in the table `stationary` so no attempt is made to insert it but to the right you see it's defined as `BOUNDFILLER` which tells `sqlldr` to remember it but don't do anything else with it.  `sqlldr` then sees other fields are defined in the control file which DO match columns in the table, so it applies the expressions and inserts the results into the corresponding columns.

The expressions operate on the saved line and pick out the data part of that line.

```
load data
infile 'file.txt'
CONCATENATE 3
into table stationary
append
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  TEMP          BOUNDFILLER CHAR(1000),
  Item_number   EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, 'Itemnumber +([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)",
  quantity      EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, 'Quantity +([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)",
  item_name     EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, 'Itemname +(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)"
)
```

Since the data element names are hardcoded in the data file, look for that and grab the data part that follows.  i.e. for `Itemnumber`, look for the text 'Itemnumber', followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more digits (which are remembered and thus returned in a group by REGEXP_SUBSTR). Repeat for the other elements.

EDIT:  Thinking about this a little, the first 2 elements can be shortened like this to grab the first and second occurrences of a number (assumes a zero will be there instead of a NULL for a zero quantity):

```
  Item_number   EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)",
  quantity      EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)",
```

Give it a try and play around with it a little.

```
Assumptions:
- Hardcoded element names won't change
- There will always be at least one space between element names and their value
- There will be no NULL item numbers or quantities (a 0 will be there)
- item_name data can't contain one of the hardcoded element names

Caveats
- The common regex shortcut of \d for a digit does not work.
```